# Fluent assertions: Assert one OR another value

Tags: c#, unit-testing, combinations, assert, fluent-assertions

Using fluent assertions, I would like to assert that a given string contains either one of two strings:

```
actual.Should().Contain("oneWay").Or().Should().Contain("anotherWay"); 
// eiter value should pass the assertion.
// for example: "you may do it oneWay." should pass, but
// "you may do it thisWay." should not pass
```

**Only if neither of the values is contained, the assertion should fail**. This does NOT work (not even compile) as there is no `Or()` operator.

This is how I do it now:

```
bool isVariant1 = actual.Contains(@"oneWay");
bool isVariant2 = actual.Contains(@"anotherWay");
bool anyVariant = (isVariant1 || isVariant2);
anyVariant.Should().BeTrue("because blahblah. Actual content was: " + actual);
```

This is verbose, and the "because" argument must get created manually to have a meaningful output.

**Is there a way to do this in a more readable manner?** A solution should also apply to other fluent assertion types, like `Be()`, `HaveCount()` etc...

I am using FluentAssertions version 2.2.0.0 on .NET 3.5, if that matters.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I would make it an extension to the string assertions. Something like this:

```
public static void BeAnyOf(this StringAssertions assertions, string[] expectations, string because, params string[] args) {
    Execute.Assertion
           .ForCondition(expectations.Any(assertions.Subject.Contains))
           .BecauseOf(because, args)
           .FailWith("Expected {context:string} to be any of {0}{reason}", expectations);
}
```

You could even fork the [repository](https://github.com/dennisdoomen/fluentassertions/tree/develop) and provide me with a [Pull Request](https://github.com/dennisdoomen/fluentassertions/pulls) to make it part of the next version.

Comment: How to use this? 
This misses a lot of explanation! It would be great if I could create something like: `actual.Should().ContainAnyOf("oneWay", "another way");` That would be consistent with the existing way.

Comment: It allows you to call `actual.Should().BeAnyOf("oneWay", "another way");`.

Comment: @DennisDoomen how could I implement that same method for Enums?

Answer (score 14):

Should not this work?

```
actual.Should().BeOneOf("oneWay", "anotherWay");
```

Worked for me using v3.1.229.

Comment: Not for me, because I do not want to assert the whole string content, but just that the actual value partially contains one of the values.

Comment: Using `.BeOneOf` works for asserting the whole string content

Answer (score 3):

You could make it a little more readable by writing a simple string extension:

```
public static class StringExt
{
    public static bool ContainsAnyOf(this string self, params string[] strings)
    {
        return strings.Any(self.Contains);
    }
}
```

Then you could do this:

```
actual.ContainsAnyOf("oneWay", "anotherWay").Should().BeTrue("because of this reason");
```

Unfortunately this doesn't help with the "reason" part of the message, but I think it's a little better.

Comment: Actually, when this fails, you have no clue what's wrong.